# Open a link with fragment

Tags: angularjs, html5mode

Previously, I used `html5mode` in my mean-stack website, now I want to disable it for some reasons, so I comment `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in my code and still leave `<base href="/1/" />` in `index.html`.

As a result, `https://localhost:3000/1/#/home` in a browser works.

However, clicking on a button defined by the following html leads to `https://localhost:3000/1/edit/`, rather than `https://localhost:3000/1/#/edit/`.

```
<li><a href="edit/" target="_self">New</a></li>
```

Does anyone know how to modify the html such that it opens `https://localhost:3000/1/#/edit/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're no longer using html5mode, I would recommend prepending the hrefs with `#/` in order to preserve your endpoints.

```
<li><a href="#/edit/" target="_self">New</a></li>
```

Without html5mode, the desired link will now cause a full page refresh. If you aren't using html5, why do you need the `#`?

It may be worth adjusting the urls to follow this pattern `https://localhost:3000/1/edit/`, unless you'd rather use my suggested code above. There may be a more elegant solution of course.